# Even and Odd function

Tags: functions

An odd function is such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

So if $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, is the function $f$ odd?

Although we have $f(-\frac{\pi}{2})=-f(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$, but $f$ is not defined for $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ in this case. So can we still say $f$ is odd?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no - but $f$ is the restriction of an odd function with domain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Odd and even functions are usaully defined on intervals symmetric about $0$. So there is no definite answer to your question. It is  a matter of conventions.

Comment: It will depend on your definition of odd. However in this case, $f$ has a unique continuous odd extension to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Dayton21 Do you mean a unique analytic continuation? If the extension is merely required to be continuous there are infinitely many possibilities.

Comment: It all depends on the definition. I'm used to a definition which says 1) if for every $x$ in a domain $(-x)$ belongs to a domain, too, and 2) for every $x$ in a domain $-f(x)=f(-x)$; then $f$ is an odd function. I can't recall the source, but I found [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddFunction.html) says simply the equality must hold, which implies if $f(x)$ exists then $f(-x)$ must exist, too. (2 B contd.)

Comment: (contd.) OTOH, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions): $f$ is odd if $-f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$ and $-x$ in the domain of $f$; which can be understood the domain needn't be symmetric and the equality needs to hold on symmetric part only. So... see the definition in your manual.

Comment: @orlp Yes the continuation will be analytic which is better, but even for continuity you really only have one choice for $f(-\pi/2)$. Any other choice will not provide continuity. Since $f$ is zero at the end points, you can have analytic extensions to larger intervals as well.

Comment: @Dayton21 This continuation is continuous, but probably not the one you were thinking of: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+piecewise%5B%7B%7B-x-pi%2F2,+x%3C%3D-pi%2F2%7D,%7Bsin(x)cos(x),+-pi%2F2%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2%7D,+%7B-x%2Bpi%2F2,+x%3E%3Dpi%2F2%7D%7D%5D+from+-pi+to+pi .

Comment: @orlp I agree but I specified a unique extension to the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. which means I am only defining $f$ at one extra point, namely $-\pi/2$. The only continuous choice for this point is $f(-\pi/2) =0$

Comment: @Dayton21 Oh... sure. I misread, and thought you meant an extension beyond that interval.